# setting border property in excel using a vbscript macro

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have a macro written with vbscript that populated an excel worksheet with data pulled from my database. I need to format a line to have a top border across 3 columns. Nothing I've tried works. Here's where I need the border

```
objExcel.Cells(rowNum + 2, 6).Value = "SUB TOTAL"
objExcel.Cells(rowNum + 2, 8).Value ="=SUM(H7:H"&finalRowNum&")"                'Extended Cost subtotal'
objExcel.Cells(rowNum + 2, 9).Value ="=SUM(I7:I"&finalRowNum&")"                'low price subtotal'
objExcel.Cells(rowNum + 2, 10).Value ="=SUM(J7:J"&finalRowNum&")"           'list price subtotal'
objExcel.Cells(rowNum + 2, 11).Value = "=H"&finalRowNum + 1&"*L"&finalRowNum + 1        'price quote'       'for included the markup going on the subtotal for all quoted items
objExcel.Cells(rowNum + 2, 12).Value ="2.00"
objExcel.Cells(rowNum + 2, 12).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 153)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work using this

```
subTotalRange = "F" &rowNum +2&":L"&rowNum + 2
objWorkSheet.Range(subTotalRange).Borders(8).linestyle= 1
```